# My alias isn't working anymore, not sure what happened

Tags: mac, bash, alias

I created an alias so that when I type `la` it does `ls -la`.

When I fire up terminal on my Mac, I get:

```
-bash: alias: la: not found
-bash: alias: =ls -la: not found
```

Why would this be?

My .bash_profile looks like:

```
alias la ='ls -la'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it needs to be:

```
alias la='ls -la'
```

(note there are no spaces around the equal sign.)

Comment: That's right, no spaces around the equal sign.

Comment: I had spaces, not sure how they got there? strange!